# Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, rspec2

I'm reading through Rails 4 in Action.  I'm getting the aforementioned error while testing with Rspec and Capybara.  My viewing_projects_spec.rb looks like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature "Viewing projects" do
  scenario "Listing all projectcs" do
    project = FactoryGirl.create(:project, name: "TextMate 2")
    visit '/'
    click_link 'TextMate 2'
    expect(page.current_url).to eql(project_url(project))
  end
end
```

The rest of the error says `Failure/Error: expect(page.current_url).to eql(project_url(project))`.

I did some googling and people say to place the following inside config/environments/development.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000'
```

Unfortunately this doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 8):

The host statement should be put into config/environments/test.rb instead of development.rb, because you are running tests.

#### Add

The reason you see 'example.com' is Capybara set this as default host. To change that, just add the following line in `spec_help` after  `require 'capybara'`

```
Capybara.default_host = 'localhost:3000'
```

Ref: https://rspec.lighthouseapp.com/projects/16211-cucumber/tickets/206

Then you urls should match what you've set in test.rb.

Anyway, I would prefer not to have that trouble to use `current_path` directly.

Comment: ok, after putting it in test I get this: `expected: "http://localhost:3000/projects/41" got: "http://www.example.com/projects/41"`

Comment: If I change to `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'www.example.com'` the test passes

Comment: @mikeglaz, it's near now. Maybe in some place you set "example.com", just grep the whole project to find it and change then should be okay.

Comment: @mikeglaz, beside, I myself prefer `current_path` than `current_url` because there is no domain in `current_path` then it's less error prone.

Comment: grep'ed the entire folder and nothing is set to example.com...very weird.

Comment: strange, this breaks all my tests.  But they all have the same error `Failure/Error: visit "/"
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: @mikeglaz, then just use `current_path`. I switched to this method long time ago because of the same reason, if I remembered correctly:) Not worthy to be stuck in an unimportant details for a long time.