# ActionView::Template::Error: Missing host to link to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

As the title implies, I'm getting this error when I try to use `link_to` in my mailer templates:

```
ActionView::Template::Error: Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
```

I tried to follow it's instructions, and I also found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114835/heroku-devise-missing-host-to-link-to-please-provide-host-parameter-or-set-d), but I'm still getting the error.

I've tried adding `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'example.com' }` to each of the following files and none of them worked:

```
/config/environment.rb
/config/application.rb (inside the module for my app)
/config/development.rb (I'm in development mode)
```

Has something changed in Rails 4 that makes this work differently?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I ran into this problem the other day and this is what ended up working for me:

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = '???'
```

**edit**

This goes in each environment file - `development.rb`, `test.rb` and `production.rb` (and more if you have them) with the corresponding host name in each one

Comment: Where? In which file did you add it?

Comment: config/application.rb is the configuration file loaded for every kind of environment (dev, prod, test, etc). The others, like config/development.rb, are loaded with the corresponding environment. So it's up to you @Emerson, you can choose depending on your needs/environments

Comment: @dax Thanks. This worked. I'm curious to know more about what this is and why it works. Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: @MrYoshiji So if config/application.rb is the global settings for environments, what is config/environment.rb? <--n00b question

Comment: I found the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16228731/2128691), but it's other places also - and it doesn't really include the 'why' unfortunately

Answer (score 15):

You've to set the default_url in each environment(development, test, production).

You need make these changes.

```
    config/environments/development.rb
     config.action_mailer.default_url_options = 
      { :host => 'your-host-name' }  #if it is local then 'localhost:3000'

 config/environments/test.rb
      config.action_mailer.default_url_options = 
      { :host => 'your-host-name' }  #if it is local then 'localhost:3000'

  config/environments/production.rb
     config.action_mailer.default_url_options = 
      { :host => 'your-host-name' }  #if it is local then 'localhost:3000'
```

Comment: Thank you. I only had this in `development.rb`; hadn't occurred to me that it had to be in `test.rb` Rails 5.0.2. Ruby 2.4.